# c# open notepad and write in other computer

Tags: c#

I have project and I want to make a receipt of a buyer and write it on the notepad but my problem is when I install my application on other computer. the notepad is not opening and nothing happen when button click

```
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\Receipt.txt");
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        string x=label1.Text.Replace(" ",string.Empty);
        string x2 = label2.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        string x3 = label3.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        string x4 = label4.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        string x5 = label5.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        w.Write("***************OFFICIAL RECEIPT*************** \r\n", true);
        w.Write("\r\n"+"\r\n"+"***************Buyer Information*************"+"\r\n");
        w.Write(x+"\r\n",true);
        w.Write(x2+ "\r\n", true);
        w.Write(x3 + "\r\n", true);
        w.Write(x4 + "\r\n", true);
        w.Write(x5+ "\r\n", true);
        w.Write("\r\n" + "***************PURCHASE ITEM*****************" + "\r\n");
        w.Write("ITEM               QUANTITY            PRICE" + "\r\n");
        for (int xx = 0; xx<listBox1.Items.Count;xx++ )
        {
            w.Write(listBox1.Items[xx].ToString()+"\r\n");
        }
        w.Write("_____________________________________________"+ "\r\n");
        w.Write("TOTAL                                   " + totalprice+"\r\n"+"\r\n");
        w.Write("         -THIS IS YOUR OFFICIAL RECEIPT-        "+"\r\n");
        w.Write("             THANK YOU FOR BUYING!        ");
        w.Close();
    }
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", path);
```

Comment: don't swallow exceptions! there is likely an exception that is being hidden and we can't help you with that.

Comment: `"and nothing happen"` - Wrong.  *Anything* could be happening.  But your code is explicitly *ignoring all errors*.  If you want to know why there's an error, examine the exception.

Comment: I think your path for Receipt.txt is incorrect .show the error message.

Comment: There's no need give the entire procedure, tidy it up a bit so we can just see the important bit.

Comment: hint look at stringbuilder and writeline.

Comment: yeah i try removing try catch and install it to my other laptop and no errors still the same... nothing happen when i click the receipt button

Comment: simply run `process.start(path)` it will open with default program or give a popup to choose the program to open with. if no message show up your path is wrong.

Comment: maybe is UnauthorizedException is thrown ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\Receipt.txt");
```

to

```
var path = Application.StartupPath + "\\Receipt.txt";
```

.

And also

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe",  path);
```

to

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", "\"" + path + "\"");
```

Changing this helped some people in some cases

providing quotes might help in case if the problem is because of empty spaces in folder names

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is winforms, as a test, change your catch block to look like this:

```
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
            throw;
        }
```

If it's working on your dev box and not on another computer, I'd be willing to bet you have a permissions issue.  Just try the code above and see what message you get.  Then you can figure out what is wrong and how to fix it.